# how to disable the url in ckeditor plugin?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor plugin for textarea.

I don't want any urls in that text. I don't know how to identify if text contains any urls or hyperlinks. Is there any way to do this? For example my code is as follows:

```
text = "hi <br> this is something about <br> www.google.com. such a good web site. <br> <a href='www.google.com'>click</a> to go <br>";
```

I need to identify urls and `href` in above code.

Comment: You need to use regex. if your using jQuery, then removing all the anchor tags in a text is very easy. `.find()` can be used for this purpose. for searching the urls in a string you have to use regex

Comment: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6307

Comment: Do you mean that you want to disable links in CKEditor? That it won't be possible to paste or create them?

Comment: yes i want to disable links and urls in CKEditor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable links in CKEditor, use the [latest 4.1.x build](http://ckeditor.com/download) and take the advantage of the [Advanced Content Filter (ACF)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

You can either basically remove link plugin by specifying `config.removePlugins = 'link'` in your config or restrict `config.allowedContent` to not to accept `<a>` tags (see ACF [configuration guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)).

This will inform your editor that links are undesired and they'll be stripped out on the editor's output.